# Dynamically adding option (tokenize.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I`m using multi*select plugin from http://zellerda.com/projects/tokenize
I noticed how I can add items to dropdown menu, but I can't figure out how can I add item to box so later I could remove it (up to this moment I manually input:

```
$('.TokensContainer').first().prepend("<li class=\"Token\" data-value='" + profilesRead[i] + "'" + "><a class=\"Close\">×</a><span>" + "Account id=".concat(profilesRead[i]) + "</span></li>"); ).
```

My problem is that when I press Close button option doesn't disappear :(
Picture for understanding : https://pp.vk.me/c629309/v629309309/317f/Cx3vfFRQO_o.jpg

I guess there must be some appropriate method for adding selected and non*selected options, but I cant find it. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding dynamic item i have following code and 
it work for me try this may it help for you

```
$('#tokenize').tokenize().dropdownAddItem("value","text");      // id of select box
$('.Tokenize .Dropdown li').trigger('click');
```